# Electron developer tools in separate window not showing on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm developing a quick proof of concept app using Electron (formerly known as atom-shell), while trying to debug it I popped the Dev tools to a separate window and it was working for a while until today. I can see the developer tools window in the windows task bar but when I click it nothing shows up.

I've tried restarting the computer, reinstalling atom, toggling developer tools via menu and Alt+Ctrl+I but the window is nowhere to be seen.

Here's the relevant code of my app, but I've tweaked it and it doesn't help either.

```
var app = require('app');
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');    

require('crash-reporter').start();

var mainWindow = null;

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  if(process.platform != 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('ready', function() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    'width': 450,
    'height': 800,
    'max-width': 450,
    'max-height': 800,
    'min-width': 450,
    'min-height': 800
  });

  mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/app/index.html');

  mainWindow.openDevTools();  

  mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
});
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I figured out how to make it appear, and in case this happens to anyone else I fixed it by just pressing **win+up**.